# Center of UIView not centered

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cashapelayer

I have a CAShapeLayer that I am adding to the center of a UIView, but instead of appearing in the center, it appears in the top left corner of the UIView.

Here's the view setup:

```
let trayProgress: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .yellow

    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: view.center, radius: 20, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: false)
    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 6
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

    return view
}()
```

Here's what is showing in the view (I expect the gray circle to be in the center of the yellow view):

[image: output]

I have also tried to replace `view.center` with `CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y)`, but I get the same result.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in part this line:

```
arcCenter: view.center
```

That makes no sense, because the view’s center is where it is in its superview. You want to make the shape layer’s frame the same as the view’s bounds! The arc center should then be the shape layer’s *own* center (which, because it is a layer, is its `position`).

But another part of the problem is that in the code you’ve shown neither the view nor the shape layer has any size. You cannot create the shape layer until the view has size.

Example (I have starred the key changes in the code):

```
let trayProgress: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 30, y: 60, width: 50, height: 50)) // *
    view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    trackLayer.frame = view.bounds // *
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: trackLayer.position, // *
        radius: 20, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: false)
    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 6
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
    return view
}()
```

Result:

[image]

You can tweak that, of course. For example you can move the center of the `view` to wherever you like.

Comment: However I should add that it is unclear to me what the `view` is for, since if all you want from the `view` is a yellow background you can give the shape layer itself that background.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand where I went wrong. I am putting the `shape` on the `view` because I am using auto-layout to position it and that cannot be done with just a `CAShapeLayer`.